# Google Cloud Storage ignoring delimiter

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to retrive JSON files from google cloud storage. The JSON files are stored in the same folder as their corresponding audio files, as follows:

```
bucket
  folder1
    audio.wav
    audio.json
  folder2
    audio.wav
    audio.json
```

I'm using nodejs, and calling cloud storage as follows:

```
bucket.getFiles({
    delimeter: 'audio' //should be preventing loading of audio files but it isnt
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

I have a feeling it might be related to how Google handles folders, but I'm not really sure. Here is how the files are being stored in the first place:

```
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

  const filename = `recordings/${path.parse(req.body.RecordingUrl).name}/audio.wav`;
  const file = storage
    .bucket(config.RESULTS_BUCKET)
    .file(filename)
```

Which results in some sort of string that assigns the audio file a unique ID as the folder name, and then appends the `/audio.wav`, and somehow cloud storage recognizes that as a folder. Just a guess, but not sure how to solve that if it's the case. Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to list all objects that end in `.json`, then you don't want to set a delimiter at all. The delimiter is used for hierarchical listing. You almost never want to set it to any values other than unset and `/`. See [list](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) documentation.

Comment: How do I exclude the audio.wav files from the result set then?

Comment: There's no way to do that. You'll have to filter at the client side.