# airflow GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor with wildcard not working file*.xml

Tags: airflow

I wanted to use filemask in the `GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor`. I cant use the `GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor` because I also need to see the ending oif the file mask. BAsically my file is like "tv_link_input_*.xml". So, tried using `GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor`, but its keep running without any OP. Using airflow 1.10.14. Code

```
check_file_gcs = GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor(
            task_id='check_file_gcs',  
            bucket=source_bucket,
            object="processing/tv_link_input_*xml",
            poke='10',
            dag=dag
            )
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Elad, Its with .xml. The file mask name is exactly "tv_link_input_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.xml".

Comment: This functionality isn't supported by google storage library. https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/d35ab3537d1828505f614d32b79b67173c9438c0/google/cloud/storage/client.py#L733 so probably worth opening a github issue requesting that functionality. If added by the google library it will be easy to do this with airflow. Without it - you will need to write custom python code that achieve that. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702835/google-cloud-storage-ignoring-delimiter